# XML Value method returns empty if chars more than 43679

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, encoding, base64

I am facing issue in retrieving string data from XML column.
I have a node in xml which consist huge data. If I try to get it with either `value` method or with `query` it is giving empty string(i.e which is equal to NULL in xml).

On debugging I came to know, the value method only retrieving data if the characters are less than or equal to **43679** in it.

I read all SO questions related to **43679** figure, that is a bug in SSMS while copying from SSMS grid. But here the issue not with SSMS. Even the SP calling from .Net application also getting the same problem.

Ex:

```
Declare  @XmlStr XML;

select @XmlStr=
'<Main>
  <Node1>/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEA.. 50000+Charcters ...</Node1>
</Main>';

SELECT @XmlStr.value('(/Main/Node1)[1]','varchar(max)') ;
```

If the Node1 contains 43679 below characters it is giving output.
Any work around? or Am I missing anything??

I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to get this as a string... The value within `<Node1>` is a `base64` encoded binary value. XML's `.value()` will implicitly recode this for you. Try this

```
Declare  @XmlStr XML;

select @XmlStr=
'<Main>
  <Node1>/9j/4gIcSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEA</Node1>
</Main>';

SELECT @XmlStr.value('(/Main/Node1)[1]','varbinary(max)') 
      ,CAST(@XmlStr.value('(/Main/Node1)[1]','varbinary(max)') AS VARCHAR(100));
```

The result shows clearly, that this is a JPEG (starts with `FFD8`). The size of `VARBINARY(MAX)` should be sufficient...

```
0xFFD8FFE2021C4943435F50524F46494C4500010100    
ÿØÿâICC_PROFILE
```

The (senseless) cast to `varchar` shows us some EXIF-data...